# Scala: Ending Stream.iterate

Tags: scala, stream, iteration, stdin

After some trial and error I found a way of **ending `Stream.iterate`** (if standard input ends in my case). But to me it seems to be more of an evil hack than a best practice solution.

**Before** (*not ending* if standard input ends because `Stream.iterate` is running infinitely):

```
val initialDocument = Document()
val in: Stream[Document] = Stream.iterate(Stream[Document]()) { documents =>
  val lastDocument: Document = documents.lastOption.getOrElse(initialDocument)
  val line: String = io.StdIn.readLine
  if(line != null) {
    line
      .split(";")
      .map(_.trim)
      .scanLeft(lastDocument)((document: Document, line: String) => document.processInput(line))
      .drop(1) // drop the seed
      .toStream
  } else {
    Stream.empty
  }
}.flatten
for(document <- in) {
  // do something with the document snapshot
}
```

**After** (now working as expected):

```
val initialDocument = Document()
val in: Stream[Document] = Stream.iterate(Stream[Option[Document]]()) { documents =>
  val lastDocument: Option[Document] = Some(documents.lastOption.flatten.getOrElse(initialDocument))
  val line: String = io.StdIn.readLine
  if(line != null) {
    line
      .split(";")
      .map(_.trim)
      .scanLeft(lastDocument)((document: Option[Document], line: String) => document.map(_.processInput(line)))
      .drop(1) // drop the seed
      .toStream
  } else {
    Stream(None) // "None" is used by "takeWhile" to see we have no more input
  }
}.flatten.takeWhile(_.isDefined).map(_.get)
for(document <- in) {
  // do something with the document snapshot
}
```

As you can see there are several new `Option` type values introduced. Their sole purpose is telling `takeWhile` if the end is reached.

How could I write this functionality in a more elegant form?

Comment: Would it work to find the terminus before flattening? `.takeWhile(_.nonEmpty).flatten`

Comment: Just tried that. If I do that together with `Stream.empty` my program terminates immediately for some reason.

Comment: I think it terminates because the `start` argument of `Stream.iterate` is set to an empty `Stream`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you are doing correctly, this will solve your problem in a simpler way:

```
val in = Iterator
  .continually(io.StdIn.readLine())       // Read all lines from StdIn infinitely
  .takeWhile(_ != null)                   // Stop on EOI
  .flatMap(_.split(';'))                  // Iterator of sublines
  .map(_.trim)                            // Iterator of trimmed sublines
  .scanLeft(Document())(_ processInput _) // Iterator of a Document snapshot per subline
  .drop(1)                                // Drop the empty Document

for (document -> in) {
  // do something with the document snapshot
}
```

Basically, first create a lazy `Iterator` of trimmed line parts from the whole input, and then make document snapshots based on this iterator.

It's best to avoid using `Stream`, unless you really need its memoization feature. `Stream` is slow, and the memoization makes it easy to cause memory leaks. `Iterator` has all the same nice methods to create finite or infinite lazy sequences, and should be the preferred collection for that purpose.

Comment: Since I was amazed by your concise solution, I tried it first, it worked, and immediately decided to stick with it. I like it a lot, many thanks.

Comment: @ideaboxer; What about `lastDocument`? Did you find that was an unneeded complication?

Comment: `lastDocument` was just the last chain link of the previous `split(";")`. Since the `scanLeft` needed some seed, I had to keep it.

Comment: The genesis of my code was as follows: First I had no `split(";")` at all in the code. Each line held exactly one command. Then I exchanged newlines by `;` as the primary separator and wrapped that command chain in the `Stream.iterate` block (which now iterated over my lines). I thought it was necessary if I wanted to deal with newlines *and* semicolons as command separators, because I thought I had to do it in a nested manner (outer: line by line; inner: command by command).

Comment: Kolmar's code seems to avoid the nesting by making use of `flatMap`, if I understand it correctly. In that context, I did not think of such a clever solution. So far I primarily used `flatMap` to flatten nested `Option` type values.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if things are getting a bit too complicated, what with the Streams within Streams, and `scanLeft()` inside `iterate()`, etc. Throwing in `Option` types in order to determine `Stream`-end has a fishy feel to it.

An `Iterator` has a natural end condition. I wonder if something like this might work better.

```
class DocItr(private var prev :Document) extends Iterator[Document] {
  private var innerItr :Iterator[Document] = _
  private var line     :String = _

  override def hasNext :Boolean = innerItr.hasNext || {
    line = io.StdIn.readLine
    Option(line).fold(false)(_.nonEmpty)
  }

  override def next() :Document = {
    if (!innerItr.hasNext) {
      innerItr = line.split(";")
                     .map(_.trim)
                     .scanLeft(prev)((doc: Document, in: String) =>
                                                       doc.processInput(in))
                     .drop(1) // drop the seed
                     .toIterator
    }
    prev = innerItr.next()
    prev
  }
}

for(document <- new DocItr(initialDocument)) {
  // do something with the document snapshot
}
```

I don't know if this will actually work. I don't have your `Document` type to work with.

I changed the "continue" condition from `line != null` to `Option(line).fold(false)(_.nonEmpty)` so that it will conclude on any empty input, not just `null`. It just made things easier for testing.